# How to include a javascript in a jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am new to J2EE and Web development. Here is my issue:
I want to include angular.js in the webpage.

Here is the version that works:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Lets Meet Up!</title>
</head>
```

But I also want to have some local javascript files, and hopefully, I want to import the angularjs in the local directory

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="WEB-INF/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <title>Lets Meet Up!</title>
</head>
```

The the page is unable to run the javascript.

My stack is Tomcat, Spring MVC, Spring, J2EE
I put the angularjs source in
    AppRoot/WebContents/WEB-INF/lib/angular

Anyone can help? THanks!!

Comment: One sub question here , will that internet based script tag
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
Work in remote deployed server that is without internet connection ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files in `WEB-INF` are inaccessible.

Put `angular.min.js` and all other static assets at the top level of your war file. Or better yet in some nice folder like `js/angular/angular.min.js` at the top level.

Then do this

```
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Depending on your needs you might want to consider serving your assets from a CDN, but that's another story altogether.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it still did't work. Just want to make sure I get your point: I am now placing the stuff in root/WebContents/angular/angular.js.

Comment: Then you should have `src="WebContents/angular/angular.js"`

Comment: Should I add anything to the web.xml or springapp-servlet.xml?  I tried but still didn't work. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Your `web.xml` should have a `url-mapping` to the Spring servlet that doesn't conflict with the URL you are using to grab your static assets.

Comment: Thanks it finally works. I actually add the resource mapping to the springapp-servet:        <mvc:resources mapping="/lib/**" location="/lib/" />  Where the lib in inside the WebContent Folder

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Can I know why exactly files under WEB-INF are not accessible.
@Vidya

Comment: plus1 for the `Files in WEB-INF are inaccessible.`

Answer (score 3):

Don't put them into WEB-INF, that folder is for the stuff that you do not want to have directly served.

Put it next to WEB-INF

+- WEB-INF

+- static

---

Comment: Should I add anything to the web.xml or springapp-servlet.xml? I tried but still didn't work. Thank you for your patience