# Connect Spring MVC .jsp to .js with Gradle

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, gradle

I am working on a Spring MVC Project with Gradle and I have a deadline coming up so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a .jsp file and I want to connect a .js file to it in order to add some Javascript functionality. I have done some research and all of the solutions use Maven which obviously wont work for what I am doing.

If I put the Javascript code in the .jsp like this:

```
<script> document.write("Hello World"); </script>
```

It works but when I try to do it in an external .js file stored in the same views file it does not.

Here are a few code snippets from the relevant files so show what I am doing:

.jsp:

```
<script src="/test.js"> </script>
```

.js:

```
document.write("Hello World");
```

If you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013072/how-to-include-a-javascript-in-a-jsp-page may be a duplicate

Comment: the key (to solve your issue) is to know/understand, where your `test.js` is (located) at "servlet runtime"... then it should work as "inline"..

Comment: (e.g.) in maven: you would put test.js under `src/main/webapp` to achieve the desired result... in any other case, you would have to "pack" test.js under the ".war root"...

Comment: and with gradle (sorry), same (as maven)! -> `src/main/webapp/test.js` ([see gradle-war-plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html))